# Run PHP 5.2.6 on windows server 2016

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2016, php-5.2

I need to install php 5.2.6 and only this version on Windows Server 2016. I don't find any packager like Windows Platform Installer or Chocolatey. With Windows Platform, the 5.2.6 version is not in the list. So I try to install manually but I can't find solution to run my test with phpinfo.php

I explain : 
I work with iis, so I test phpinfo.php into C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php and try to call phpinfo() with http://localhost/phpinfo.php and I try several way :

1. In Mapping manager, I set php5isapi.dll in script mapping and the result is : 
   Error http 404.17 - Not Found 
   [image]
2. I copied php-cgi.exe from the old server and paste it in the new PHP folder. Set this file on mapping manager , add a mapping module and browse the php=cgi.exe and set the FastCgiModule. I have the 500 error..

[image]

Also try without any mapping setting and still not  working (error 404.3)

If anyone can help me... Thanks a lot!

Comment: PHP 5.2 hasn't been supported since 6 Jan 2011! If you have code that depends on it, fix that code. You've had a decade to do that already.

Comment: You might run some diagnostics https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/php-diagnostics.html But I agree that you shouldn't use PHP 5.2 any longer.

Comment: I agree too but I don't have the choice now.  Thanks for the link @LexLi

Comment: Don't attempt the complete IIS integration in one step. The first thing I'd try is to ensure that PHP simply runs on the computer (e.g., running `php -v` in the command-line). Error 500 just means "find the error message in the log file".

Comment: Yes I try php-v and it' says that it's missing php_oci8.dll and I don't use oracle ...? (PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_oci8.dll' - Le module spÚcifiÚ est introuvable.
 in Unknown on line 0)

Comment: I checked php_oci8.dll is in the ext folder

Comment: You don't need the OCI8 extension if you don't use Oracle.

Comment: I just activated application in 32 bits in application pools and it's working...